# On the (short) proof of integration by parts

Tags: calculus

Consider the proof of integration by parts given here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegrationbyParts.html .

I do not understand this equality: $\int d(uv)=uv$.

Of course I am missing something, but it seems to me that we should say $\int d(uv)=uv+c$ where $c$ is a constant. Where am I mistaken?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true; however, since the equation
$$ uv = \int u \, dv + \int v \, du $$
still has integrals in it, the arbitrary constant can be absorbed into the right-hand side.